# Set chromedriver window size before opening in selenium (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When my script opens the chromedriver (`driver = webdriver.Chrome()`) in Windows 10, the window maximizes to full size on my monitor. To minimize disruption, I would prefer it was barely noticeable. The closest I can get is the following:

```
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.set_window_size(1, 1)
```

This works well in that the window size is minimal. Unfortunately, it still first pops open to the full monitor and then readjusts to the preferred minimal size. Is there any way to preset the window size before opening up the chromedriver?

Comment: I'm looking at the accepted answer and I'm looking at your question and you know what? What is in the accepted answer is exactly what I understood you were doing from reading your question. So... your question is unclear (the fact that one user was able to read your mind does *not* make it clear). Please edit it with the actual test code you were using and *then* it will be a useful question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place `driver.set_window_size(1,1)` in the setup method for example:

```
class ExampleTestSuite(unittest.TestCase):
   def setUp(self):
      self.driver= webdriver.Chrome()
      self.driver.set_window_size(1,1)

  def test_example_test(self):
     #test code here
```

What I think you really are looking for is running your tests headless. One way to do it this describe in this post: http://fgimian.github.io/blog/2014/04/06/headless-browser-testing-with-chrome-and-firefox/.

Another option is to use a cloud based testing service like Sauce Labs, or Browserstack.

Answer (score 3):

I actually came across a pretty good alternative to @user3277225's answer. It turns out you can set options for the Chrome webdriver and then open it as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1,1")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: This is an interesting alternative. However,  if you are running selenium tests across multiple browser it is seems like it would be easier to just set the browser window in the setup method, as opposed to setting options for each browser.